# Eclipse has some problems with auto import static classes

Tags: eclipse, import, static-classes

I have some problems with eclipse.

if I use something like `anyMap()` in my source code, and press then `CTRL + SHIFT + O` no update in the import list will be done.
If I write something like: `import static org.mockito.Matchers.*` into my imports, the `anyMap()` is then known.
If press then `CTRL + SHIFT + O` because i had to import some other classes, the `import static org.mockito.Matchers.*` will be replaced by `import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyMap`

If I want to use then `anyList()`, i have to write the import `import static org.mockito.Matchers.*` by hand again.

I know this topic [Can Eclipse the Organize Import (ctrl+shift+o) command's handling of static imports be modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831047/can-eclipse-the-organize-import-ctrlshifto-commands-handling-of-static-impo) and the solution works fine, but is there also a possibility so eclipse automatically knows the static classes i wanna use?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes this is possible .. see this question :

[Eclipse Optimize Imports to Include Static Imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288861/eclipse-optimize-imports-to-include-static-imports)

Check the Favorite preference section:
**Window » Preferences » Java  » Editor » Content Assist » Favorites**

Click 'New Type' and add `org.mockito.Matchers` like so :

[image: Add a New Type]

Once you do that, you should have the corresponding entry there like so :

[image: Entry Appears]

After that, if you type `anyM` in the code and do a Ctrl+Space you will see that the static method is one of the content assist proposals. If you choose that, the corresponding import is automatically added :

[image: Proposal]

If you type something that matches nothing but the static, the import will automatically be added. For example if you typed `anyMap` and *then* pressed Ctrl + Space the import will directly be added.

Comment: a short question again: it works perfect for autocompletion - but it's still not working by pressing `CTRL + o`

Comment: `Ctrl + o` is to open a resource in the workspace. Did you mean `Ctrl + Shift + o` to organize imports ?

Comment: sorry, yes i mean `CTRL + SHIFT + O` - it's not importing the static classes, it will only import by autocompletion

Comment: @Joerg, I could not find a way to include static imports when doing an Organize Imports (Ctrl + Shift + O). However the fast code plugin was very helpful while adding static imports : http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/documentation.htm (Search for `Create Import`).