# Shortcut to get rid of full class names

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I have a lot of lines of code that are similar to this:

```
objectListPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
roomNameField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
rightPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
jTabbedPane = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
enterScriptPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
```

in that they all use the "Fully Qualified Name" for a class. Is there a way to quickly fix all of these to just use the class name?

```
objectListPanel = new JPanel();
roomNameField = new JTextField();
rightPanel = new JPanel();
jTabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
enterScriptPanel = new JPanel();
```

Comment: If there are multiple files with different import then replace all fully qualified values using regex them manually import it using shortcuts.

Comment: Someone forget to leave the comment when it's down voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find `new javax.swing.` and replace with `new` and then import it in the class.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> keyboard shortcuts to organize imports automatically.

[read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831047/can-eclipse-the-organize-import-ctrlshifto-commands-handling-of-static-impo)

Answer (score 1):

can you use an import?
try placing the below line at the top of your java file.

```
import javax.swing.*;
```

Comment: @Braj I'd agree in the case of an IDE, though if you do CL java, it becomes a lifesaver sometimes.

Comment: he says he has "a lot of lines". My cut off before a wildcard import is about 15. Eclipse's organize imports merges to a wildcard at 99.